# Why am I getting a connectionTimeout error while trying to update my chef node?

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, chef-infra

I keep getting this error on the Chef tutorial while trying to update my node. Its very strange because I was able to bootstrap in and ssh in using the same credentials. I have also confirmed that my security for inbound ports for 80, 20 and 443 were open. For the life of me I can't understand why it's holding up here. I am using MacOSX and terminal with an AWS virtual.

```
WARNING: Failed to connect to 172.31.46.107 -- Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout: Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout
```

---

```
knife ssh 'name:node1-centos' 'sudo chef-client' --ssh-user centos --identity-file /Users/gavindevops/.ssh/GavinChefKeyPair.pem --attribute ipaddress
```

Answer (score 0):

SSH uses port 22. Was that a typo in the question or in the security group?

Comment: Nah, I did accidentally not update the security groups in a prior instance, but I fixed that issue quick, so I think that can be ruled out. I figured out the answer though. Stupid tut didn't include the necessary info in every route you could go through. i.e. They left out some info for key auth that was included in password and user auth. Thanks for the response though!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so turns out even if you're using key based authentication, scroll down to the user name and password instructions part of the tutorial because it tells you to use "cloud.public_hostname" in place of "ipaddress" if you are using a service like AWS.